# How can I get a typescript object property to accept a union of an array (of objects) or object?

Tags: typescript

first stack overflow question, so hopefully I'm asking in an useful manner and apprecate all assistance :-)

I have an interface that whose property 'location' requires flexibility as either an array of objects or an object itself. Currently my structure declaration is as follows:

```
export interface InitialValues {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  website: string;
  category: string;
  logo?: object;
  banner?: object;
  location: Location[] | Location;
}

interface Location {
  address: string;
  phone: string;
  lat: string;
  lng: string;
  availability: [
    {
      day: string;
      from: string;
      to: string;
    }
  ];
}
```

Where:
const values: InitialValues = {...}

and later on depending on the value of a parameter variable (campaign: booelan), a defining of values.location as such:

```
if (campaign) {
      values.location.address = results[0].formatted_address;
      values.location.lat = latlng.lat;
      values.location.lng = latlng.lng;
    } else if (!campaign) {
      values.location[index].address = results[0].formatted_address;
      values.location[index].lat = latlng.lat;
      values.location[index].lng = latlng.lng;
    }
```

This of course isn't working out for me, and I'm getting errors that properties address, lat and lng do not exist on type Location | Location[]. However, removing Location from the union allows for the else if statements to clear error. My understanding is because unions are only valid for numbers, strings and boolean types.

Hopefully, this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: What if `campaign` is true but `values.location` is `Location[]` instead of `Location`?

Comment: You need to use [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in order to tell the compiler that the if check allows the type to be narrowed down

Comment: @Aplet123 if true, the location object is on a different Model where its schema sets it as an object.

Comment: @PhuNgo - okay great. I'm still relevatively fresh with typescript and had actually looked over that in the handbook. but great to know what to hone in on

Comment: @PhuNgo would you mind helping out with an example - I'm still having some trouble getting this right.

Comment: @coderDick something like this [codesandbox Link with type guards](https://codesandbox.io/s/73ir9?file=/index.ts) or even cleaner, [codesandbox Link with built-in type guard Array.isArray](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-r8btq?file=/index.ts), or if you want a better design, have InitialValues be a class and define a method to process `results` and `latlng` values

Comment: @PhuNgo - omg i didnt see this - thanks! I'm much better at TS now lol